# What is sigma for a time series and how to calculate it

Tags: time-series, forecasting, standard-deviation, noise

Trying to apply changepoint detection. Many algorithms such as Binary segmentation and PELT use sigma ( std deviation ) as a parameter if the number of changepoints are unknown.

Confused if sigma is std deviation of noise or std deviation of time series data itself. Also is there a formula to calculate it as std deviation f the noise ?